# What happens if more than one Jest configuration is used simultaneously?

Tags: unit-testing, configuration, jestjs, combinations

[Jest's configuration](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html) states:

> Jest's configuration can be defined in the `package.json` file of your
>   project, or through a `jest.config.js` file or through the `--config <path/to/js|json>` option.

What happens if a configuration setting is defined in two or more places? Are distinct configuration settings merged together or can they be silently ignored? If merging or ignoring, do they have a well defined or ad hoc precedence?

Answer (score 2):

I inherited multiple projects with both a "jest" object in package.json and "jest.config.js" file, each with their specific configuration.

By playing (superficially) with the coverage threshold (which was < 97%), I came to the conclusion that **jest.config.js** is used, and the jest object in package.json is ignored. There doesn't seem to be any merging going on.

My tests:

#1: Which has priority ?

- package.json: coverage 98%
- jest.config.js: coverage 99%
- => "coverage threshold for statements (99%) not met"
- Answer: jest.config.js

#2: Are they merged ?

- package.json: coverage 98%
- jest.config.js: (missing coverage key)
- => no coverage warnings
- Answer: No

Answer (score 0):

To answer a subset of the full problem (which may be too complicated for a meaningful set of tests as it's a lot of knobs to twiddle), **if a jest command line `--config` (or `-c`) is provided, then package.json jest settings are ignored.**

More specifically to come to this conclusion, firstly I tried `jest -c jest/config.js` with [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) in my `jest/config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  rootDir: '../',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest/global-setup.js'],
}
```

File `jest/global-setup.js` contains:

```
const Enzyme = require('enzyme')
const Adapter = require('enzyme-adapter-react-16')
require('jest-enzyme/lib/index.js')

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

Which here has the desired effect of running the [enzyme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme) setup. Commenting it out in the `jest/config.js` file and putting the equivalent into `package.json` is skipped/ignored:

```
"jest": {
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./jest/global-setup.js"],
},
```

Secondly I tried `jest -c jest/config.js` with a [jest fileTransformer.js](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#mocking-css-modules) file and the following in my `jest/config.js`:

```
transform: {
  '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
  '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
  '<rootDir>/jest/file-transformer.js',
},
```

Then the equivalent [`jest.transform`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#transform-object-string-pathtotransformer-pathtotransformer-object) setting of package.json is skipped/ignored:

```
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/jest/file-transformer.js"
  }
},
```

Thirdly, changing my [`npm scripts`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) `test` command from `jest -c jest/config.js` to `jest` and my `package.json` to include the following causes the `package.json` settings to work as expected:

```
"jest": {
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./jest/global-setup.js"],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
    "<rootDir>/jest/file-transformer.js"
  }
},
```

Tested with [jest v24.9.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest/v/24.9.0)